# Error creating a Postgres DB in AWS RDS using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, boto3, amazon-rds, psycopg2

I want to create a Postgresql database in AWS RDS using Python, but this error appears when I want to create the DB in the instance, even when I want to create it from scratch.

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "xxxxx.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (xx.xxx.xx.15), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "carlo" does not exist
```

Here's my code:

```
import os
import boto3
import psycopg2

os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = "xxxxxxx"
os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "xxxxxxxxx"
os.environ["AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"] = "us-east-1"

instance_name = input("Name of your instance: ") #assign a name to the instance for the db
instance_class = "db.t3.micro"
user = "user"
password = "password"
host = "xxxx.xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
port = 5432
db_name = "carlo"

def create_instance_rds(instance_name, db_name, instance_class, user, password):
    """Create new database instance in RDS"""
    client = boto3.client('rds')
    response = client.create_db_instance(
        DBInstanceIdentifier=instance_name,
        DBName=db_name,
        Engine='postgres',
        AllocatedStorage=20,
        DBInstanceClass=instance_class,
        MasterUsername=user,
        MasterUserPassword=password,
        MultiAZ=False,
        PubliclyAccessible=True,
        StorageType='gp2',
        Tags=[{
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Value': instance_name
        }]
    )
    return response

def create_connection():
    """Create a connection to the RDS instance"""

    connection = psycopg2.connect(
        host = "xxxxxx.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
        port = port,
        user = user,
        password = password,
        #database=db_name
        )
    connection.autocommit = True
    with connection.cursor() as cur:
        db_name = db_name
        cur.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {db_name}")

    cursor = connection.close()

    return cursor

def create_table(table_name, attributes):
    """Create a table in AWS RDS instance"""
    client = boto3.client('rds-data')

    # Define the SQL statement for creating the table
    sql_statement = f"CREATE TABLE {table_name} ({attributes})"

    # Execute the SQL statement
    create_connection().execute(sql_statement)




create_instance_rds(instance_name, db_name, instance_class, user, password)

table_name = input("Ingrese el nombre de la tabla: ")
attributes = input("Ingrese los atributos separados por coma (por ejemplo: 'id INT, name VARCHAR(255), age INT'): ")

create_table(table_name, attributes)
```

I want to create the database from scratch but the code returns this error.
Obviously the DB doesn't exist, that's why I want to create it haha.
I don't know if there's something I didn't saw.

Comment: It is possible that the error is invoked by create_table directly after creating instance. Creating RDS instance is not instant as it takes some time AFAIK.